# Sending a string in C++ MPI

Tags: c++, c, string, mpi

TL;DR I believe I am incorrectly transmitting a string with MPI_Send. What is the best way to send a string?

---

I'm trying to send a string from the master to the slave processes but I believe it's not sending the entire string or not reconstructi9ng it properly at the slave end.

Master MPI_Send code:

```
MPI_Send(&parent, sizeof(char) * selection::target_length(), MPI_BYTE, i, MSEND, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Slave MPI_Recv Code:

```
char parentChars [selection::target_length()];

MPI_Recv(&parentChars, sizeof(char) * selection::target_length(), MPI_BYTE, 0, MSEND, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

parent = parentChars;
```

The assertion `assert(target.length() == candidate.length());` fails and gives the following results:

```
weasel: weaselparallel.cpp:34: static int selection::fitness(std::string): Assertion `target.length() == candidate.length()' failed.
```

↑ This is output for each slave process

And then there's the segmentation fault that I assume occurs because of the incorrectly transmitted string:

```
mpiexec noticed that process rank 2 with PID 23531 on node node02.emperor exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).

6 total processes killed (some possibly by mpiexec during cleanup)
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `parent`?

Comment: It looks here like you're mixing C and C++, too.  `parentChars` looks like a C VLA, but you have `::` operators in there.  Which is it, C or C++?

Comment: You should know that this isn't pure C++ code, [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (i.e. your `parentChars` array) is not part of C++, though some compilers allow it as an extension. You should not use it if you want your code to be portable.

Comment: The :: operator is for accessing a public class used as a handler. I know the code is pretty horrible but it's the skeleton code I was given and have to use. I've done the rest but just need to get the send right. parent is just declared as a string ie: `string parent;` and parentChars is declared like this: `char parentChars [selection::target_length()];`. Portability isn't an issue. Thanks for your feedback so far.

Answer (score 0):

- Check definition of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv, I think something is wrong
  with your first argument.
- Try omitting the ampersand symbol( & ) of parent and/or parentChars depends on your definition
- also check the status( speifically, MPI_ERROR ) return from MPI_Recv for more information on what is happening